# How to insert a background image over full page width with a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the Bootstrap grid and now I want to insert a background image. However it is not spanning over the full width of the page, it just stays within the borders of the defined columns in the rows.

Right now:
[image: Right now]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/ccfb38-1565964919.png))</sub>

As I want it to be:
[image: As I want it to be]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/c5c703-1565964874.png))</sub>

```
<div class="background-image">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `container` div in a `container-fluid` div and apply a background to *that*

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.background-image {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid background-image">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
              <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
              <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

can u use container-fluid ?